# Regular expression stop after first match

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have the following pattern

```
work
sleep
work
eat
```

I need a regular expression that finds only the first word `work` and not all of them, I've never understood regular expressions.

L.E: I'm using JavaScript and I want to match the word `work` not the first word whatever that word is

Comment: Using what language/tool?

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/xT7yD8/3

Comment: Do you mean first word, whether it be the word "work: or not? Or do you mean the first time the specific word, "work" appears?

Comment: @anubhava I'm using javascript

Comment: @MattCremeens I want to replace the specific word ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are matching it globally. I don't know for what purpose nor where you need it.

Check it here http://regexpal.com/

Make sure you have unchecked the global check button.

If you match it globally it searches the whole document/text and match it everywhere it can. This is why you get `work` matched twice

Answer (score 1):

`I've never understood regular expressions.`

So why you want to use them? If you do not understand them, use a different approach using string/array operations. You should never use code you don't understand - cause if in doubt you would not be able to fix it!

String example: Use your programing languages `indexOf()` method to find the start position of "work".

Array example: Split the string at the occurence of `searchtag` - and check if you have more than one result.

If you just need to figure out IF the string appears, use `.contains()` etc...

---

Comment: I can't use a different approach, I'm using a tool not the code itself, this tool use only javascript regex

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in javascript

```
text.match(/(work)/);
```

Comment: I need only the regular expression, i don't have access to any function.

Comment: Then just `/(work)/` should do. By omitting the global tag, `g`, you will get just the first instance of `work`.